# Why were my comments deleted from this question about Israel?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

At [Military aid Israel has received from the US](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26810/military-aid-israel-has-received-from-the-us) , I posted a comment saying that I was voting to close the question because it's trivially googleable.

If any country has had foreign aid from the US scrutinised by the general public, it's been Israel. It's the country which would be easiest to google an answer for. The topic has been a constant talking point for some people. I've tried to avoid using the "bad faith" close reason, but if any question qualifies as bad faith, that would be one of them.

The OP hasn't addressed the comment, so it isn't obsolete. The question has been closed and re-opened, but it wasn't the result of the question being fixed.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is trivially googleable

This is not a helpful comment. First, we don't close questions that are "trivially googleable". If you feel the question lacks prior research, downvote it.

Second, the comment does nothing to help improve the question, its only purpose is to critisize it. That goes against our [commenting guidelines](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> **When shouldn't I comment?**
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> - Suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;
> - Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);
> - Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and pay it forward;
> - **Criticisms which do not add anything constructive ("-1, see previous comments you scallywag!"); instead, down-vote (and provide or up-vote a better answer if appropriate);**
> - Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;
> - Discussion of community behavior or site policies; please use meta instead.

I've removed the comment again. Please avoid posting similar comments in the future.

Comment: While "trivially googleable" isn't a close reason (thanks $deity), the fact that it IS trivially googleable is a very good indicator that the question was asked in bad faith, which IS indeed a close reason on Politics.SE

Comment: That's a stretch...

Comment: @user4012 Don't confuse laziness with bad faith; many trivially searchable answers get posted on e.g. Stack Overflow. That is clearly not done in bad faith.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker - on SO, they get posted because someone needs their work done for them. This question has no such "redeeming" quality - anyone even remotely interested in the topic would have been already inundated with info well before resorting to Politics.SE . I can MAYBE buy that it was a attempt at rep gathering, but Hanlon's razor clearly doesn't apply in this specific case

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the comment because it was about to escalate to a discussion. I restored the comment for now, but if it again starts to become a discussion about something else than how to improve the question, I am going to delete it again.

Comment: If someone else engages in inappropriate behaviour, delete their comments, not mine, unless there's something inappropriate about my comment.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Comments are ephemeral, don't get attached to them. Also, although your comment is not inappropriate, your close vote is. "trivially googleable" is a reason to downvote, not vote to close.